# Marker disappears when changing its symbol in plotly express

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am currently doing a scatter map of Colombia with some points that need to be differentiated according to a categorical variable. The color changes fine but it suddenly stops showing on the map when I try to change its symbol. Oddly enough, it still comes up in the legend.

This is my code:

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(datos, lat="latitud", lon="longitud", hover_name="id_direccion",
                        zoom=1, center=dict(lat=7, lon=-74.2973328), 
                        mapbox_style="open-street-map",
                        hover_data=["Origen"],
                        color = "Origen"
                        )


fig.update_layout(title="Coordinadora")
fig.update_layout(mapbox_bounds={"west": -83, "east": -65, "south": -5, "north": 16})
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=700)

fig.show()
```

[image: Output map without changing marker symbols]

I tried to use this line of code but that's when the issue arises:
`fig.update_traces(marker={"symbol": "circle-open", }, selector={"name": "here"})`

[image: Output map changing marker symbols]

It is worth noting that I have a DataFrame called datos with four columns: `latitud`, `longitud`, `id_direccion`, and `Origen`. Origen is categorical and it can take values such as `here` or `GPS`, etc.

Comment: This is a bit old, but the plotly community has a [note](https://community.plotly.com/t/solved-symbol-changes-not-showing-up-with-scattermapbox/16381) regarding mapbox markers. I tried to create similar data and change the symbols, but only circle type was possible.